# How do I make text not appear in a TextField?

Tags: javafx, textfield

Well... I have a TextField and I would like the typed text not to appear in the component, just be read.

The reason for this is that I want to read a key using the onKeyPressed event and display the key pressed through the getEvent (). GetName () methods of a KeyEvent.

But there are problems:

- when you press the Delete key, the letter 'D' is deleted from the TextField text.
- when you press the Space key, a space is added at the beginning.
- ...

This is my code:

```
this.myTextField.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
    shortcut = event.getCode();
    myTextField.setText(shortcut.getName());
});
```

- shortcut is a KeyCode
- myTextField is a TextField

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Could you just grab the pressed key and clear the `TextField`?

Comment: Or maybe use something like [this](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/restricting-input-on-a-textfield/). That way you can grab the text, but make all text invalid. Then just set the `TextField`'s text to empty string.

Comment: I believe that adding constraints would not be a good solution, as the Delete key would continue deleting the first letter. As for the option to clear the contents of TextField, I even tried it, but it seems the thread that changes the contents of a TextField is called after my event is called, so even clearing the content and inserting a new one, TextField will make changes after.

Comment: But I found a solution and I'm editing a answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...
I've found a solution, and it's very simple.

I only changed the TextField to a Button. Yes, that's it (with a bit of CSS, of course).

The Button has the same events and it have the possibility to set a text. That's all I needed.

Comment: While your solution may work, I would not recommend getting in the habit of convoluted workarounds like this. A much better solution would be to just listen for keystroke and then clear the TextField.

Comment: I tried clearing the TextField, but the java threads change the contents of the object after my event runs.

Comment: Also, the only changes in my code were the declaration of the object, in which I switched from TextField to Button, and the getter and setter of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnKeyReleased` instead of `setOnKeyPressed` method

```
textField.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            KeyCode key = e.getCode();
            textField.setText(key.getName());
        });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using combination keys like Ctrl + P, and this onKeyReleased event does not let me use this. What's more, it simply hides the contents after the event is called, so if the user holds down a key, like the 'c', it will continue to appear "cC". Is there no way for TextFiel not to display what it is typing?